# Redirect to different webpage based on URL entered

Tags: php, javascript, python, url, redirect

I am trying to create a script to redirect users to a different URL based on the URL entered.

Ex:

test.foo.com/1234 redirects to a.b.com/abc/def?info=1234

or

test.foo.com/9999 redirects to a.b.com/abc/def?info=9999

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you really redirecting cross-domain (not just internally in your app)?

Comment: Yes, the redirect is cross-domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTACCESS to do this most effectivley.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://a.b.com/abc/def?info=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to extract the requested page in your php script.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Then do this to redirect the user

`header("Location: http://www.abc.com/");`

Example:

```
<?php
  $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $request = trim($request, '/');

  //there can be no output before this line
  header("Location: http://www.abc.com/def?info=".$request);
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: This will work, but with mod_rewrite to direct all URLs to execute the php script. After all, this is /1234, rather than /?1234

Comment: @ksiegel This question didn't tag anything about servers or .htaccess files so I neglected to mention a solution like yours. Having said that, you are correct. Your solution would be the best way.